# How to read blob data from SQL Server Image field using Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql-server, blob, dapper

I need to read blob data into a memory stream from an Image type column from an SQL Server database. How can I do this using Dapper?

I was reading the Dapper manual but was unable to find information about this.

UPDATE: I need to read the data from the database (from a query). All the links suggested so far has information about how to store the blob in the database.

Comment: Did you go through the following link : https://dapper-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/9634587/using-dapper-with-blobs-and-sql-server-ce

Comment: Yes I saw both but neither seems to be relevant. I need to read from the server using a query. The links explain how to do it when need to update and insert above 8k data.

Comment: `image` is the deprecated name for `varbinary(max)`. Don't use `image`

Comment: @AmitJoshi that question has no relevant answer. It's far too old anyway - Dapper went through a *lot* of changes in the last 7 years

Comment: @RasanjanaN that's just a reposting of [a very old SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9634587/using-dapper-with-blobs-and-sql-server-ce) with no relevant answer. That site is **NOT** an official Dapper site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The result dynamic type is a byte[].

```
var row = con.QueryFirst("SELECT BLOBFIELD FROM TABLE WHERE ID = 1");

byte[] bytes = drawings.BLOBFIELD;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Temp\Test.dat", System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew))
  stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: In other words, create an object with a `byte[]` field. The rest of the code isn't relevant. This won't work with *large* binaries though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how it can be made to work with large binaries?